# Every line is giving Errors in Vite

Tags: reactjs, frontend, vite

[I am Continuosly getting these kind of small errors even of semicolon error which is optional in react but when i run the app its completely working fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SG3tO.png)

I tried Relocation vite dependencies from devDependecies to dependencies but didn't helped me .

Comment: Please get in the habit of reading errors, don't ignore them like you are now!

Comment: Try the quick fix.

Comment: @Andy Ray I did read all the errors but they were just normal errors which dont have meaning 
Like indentation gap should be 14 char instead of 12

Comment: You are right its not a code error but it's an error produced by eslint. Eslint is for linting code. You can change or disable the `react/jsx-indent` rule. https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-indent.md.